# How to reuse theme-ui theme in Gatsby react-live code block component?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, theme-ui

I'm working on MDX code block component based on [theme-ui-gatsby-plugin](https://theme-ui.com/packages/gatsby-plugin/),
[prism-react-renderer](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer) and [react-live](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-live).

What's the best way to reuse the same syntax highlighting theme for `react-live` and `react-prism-renderer` components taking into account that `react-live` renders `pre` tag
and `prism-highlight` component renders `<pre><code>` tags.

- [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/iamskok/skok.io/tree/feature/react-live-code-block)
- [Example of syntax highlighting](https://ch48i.sse.codesandbox.io/blog/ninth-blog-post/)

```
System:
  OS: macOS 10.15.3
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node: 11.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.14.0/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.19.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.14.0/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.11.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.14.0/bin/npm
Languages:
  Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
Browsers:
  Chrome: 79.0.3945.130
  Firefox: 72.0.2
  Safari: 13.0.5
npmPackages:
  gatsby: ^2.19.12 => 2.19.12
  gatsby-image: ^2.2.39 => 2.2.40
  gatsby-plugin-mdx: ^1.0.67 => 1.0.70
  gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.1.21 => 3.1.22
  gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.3.13 => 2.4.5
  gatsby-plugin-theme-ui: ^0.3.0 => 0.3.0
  gatsby-remark-images: ^3.1.42 => 3.1.44
  gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.1.46 => 2.1.48
  gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.3.13 => 2.3.14
npmGlobalPackages:
  gatsby-cli: 2.8.29
  gatsby: 2.5.7
```

Related:  https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui/issues/212, https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/702